# Including Signed Libraries in Executable JAR with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, cryptography, maven-plugin

Maven *shade* and *assembly* plugins first unpack and then add dependencies to the executable jar. This can produce a conflict with Java Cryptography Extension, since the libraries like BouncyCastle should be used in their signed versions. 
**Question:** Is there a way to create executable jar with maven in a way that the libraries are included without unpacking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard classloader will not load classes from another jar, hence the exploded jar.  The best way to achieve adding the signed jars is using the -cp command, something like :

```
java -cp signedjar;shadepluginjar Main
```